# Unable to position a Fab Button in a UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, uiview, material-ui, floating-action-button, cosmicmind

Problem: I have a custom class inheriting from a `UITableViewController`. I am trying to position a Fab button from Material within the view.

However, since the superview of the controller is a `UITableView`, and not a simple `UIView`, the Fab button isn't appearing when using

> view.layout.width().height().right().bottom()

How do I position the Fab button, and make it appear, when the superview is *not* a `UIView`?

And since my custom class inherits from `UITableViewController`, I can't simply use a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` embedded without much additional work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `layout.width().height()` you are using the default value of that chained function, which is `0`. So you should put a value like this: `width(64).height(64)`. Also, you need to set the layout child view, like so: `view.layout(fabButton).width(64).height(64).bottom(16).right(16)`. Notice in the `layout` function we are passing in the `fabButton`.